# Append question mark to url retrofit android

Tags: android, networking, get, retrofit

Good day.I want to get the url like this `http//:www.someurl.com/someRedirect/anotherRedirect/?searchCriteria`

the issue is that i cant append the question mark to the retrofit,if i do it like this

```
@GET("someRedirect/anotherRedirect/{searchCriteria}")
    Call<ResponseBody> getProductsList(@Path("searchCriteria") String appendedUrl);
```

and call this method with appending the ? mark,it will just put some weird %3fb or something,and if i do like this

```
@GET("someRedirect/anotherRedirect/")
    Call<ResponseBody> getProductsList(@Query("searchCriteria") String appendedUrl);
```

The retrofit will give link like `http//:www.someurl.com/someRedirect/anotherRedirect/?searchCriteria=searchCriteria`...what the hell is wrong with this library?How to simply build my desired url?

Comment: have you figured this out?

Comment: yup, just accepting the answer below as it is the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Retrofit 1 or 2? In any case, Retrofit URL-encodes paths by default. You can easily disable it, though:

If you use 1, then you should use `@EncodedPath` instead of `@Path`.

If you use 2, then you should use `@Path(value = "searchCriteria", encoded = true)`.

Comment: using 2nd,ok let me try that

Comment: trying again with more options,but i think your idea is the solving one